# Calling a C++ function from Qt (slot does not work)

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have written a client-server program in c++. Now I have to use QT to create the interface.
I have created a login interface. When I click login button, it should call the sendmessage function, which sends the username and password to a server (Also written in C++) which verifies it and sends back true or false to the sendmessage function. If it's true, the window should close and open a new window, or else it should again show the login window, so that the user can try again. Now, how to bring this about, the loops and whether it's possible to use signals and slots to call a c++ function. Some ideas would be nice on how to do this

Here's an idea of my code:

```
 Log::Log(QWidget *parent)
:QWidget(parent){

    QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout(this);
    grid->setSpacing(20);

    QLabel *username = new QLabel("Username", this);
    grid->addWidget(username, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    edt1 = new QLineEdit(this);
    grid->addWidget(edt1, 0, 1, 1, 3);

    QLabel *password = new QLabel("Password", this);
    grid->addWidget(password, 1, 0, 1, 1);

    edt2 = new QLineEdit(this);
    grid->addWidget(edt2, 1, 1, 1, 3);

    QPushButton *login = new QPushButton("Login", this);
    grid->addWidget(login, 3, 4, 1, 1);

    setLayout(grid);

    connect(login, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(send_message()));

}
 //Other code


bool send_message(){
     buff = edt1->text() + edt2->text();
    write(socket, buff_send, 256); //Sends to the server
    read(socket, buff_recv, 256); //Gets the reply from the server
    if(buff_recv==true){
          loginwin.close();
          return true}
    else return false;
   }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Login logwin;
    logwin.move(300, 300);
    logwin.setWindowTitle("LOGIN");
    window.show();
}
```

I know it's quite wrong. But I hope you got what I was trying to say and give some techniques on how to do this.

Comment: Can you please show us your error messages. Probably you need to declare Q_SLOT: send_message but inside you class. Each slot you'll call needs to be registered as a slot.

Comment: You may want to ``QApplication::exec()`` your app in main function. Otherwise no Qt Event loop will be running. Actually your Application should immediatly shut down again. Even what is ``window`` in your main-function? This would not compile at all.

Comment: This code isn't really the actual code, it's just a sort of psuedo code. I just need an idea how to do the above mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just register a Qt slot within your header file.

```
class Log {
  ...
  Q_SLOTS:
    void sendMessage ();
}
```

and implement the slot in the implementation, e.g. by:

```
Log::sendMessage() {
  send_message();
}
```

Do not forget to change `connect` statement to just the `sendMessage()` function rather than your `send_message` function.

Comment: Okay. I can do that. But If I need to pass arguments to send_message() and get it's return value? Can a slot have arguments?

Comment: Also, how can I make the login window run inside a while loop. When I do so, it seems to hang up.

Comment: @CherryCool Of couse slots may have arguments. If you haven't code any  Qt applications. Please try the tutorials from various Qt website, before asking questions that are already answered.